# How to subtract a list from certain sublists of a list?

Tags: vector, list-manipulation, operators

I have a problem in doing an operation on this vector

```
 {{2,3},{3,4},{5,6}}-{1,1}
```

I want to minus this to get the result

```
{{1,2},{3,4},{4,5}}
```

Comment: That `{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} - {1, 1}` does not work, whereas something like `{1, 2, 3} - 1` does work, seems a fundamental language design limitation.

Comment: @murray With all due respect I think that you have misread the desired output of the OP. It appears that the author wants to subtract `{1,1}` **ONLY** from the first and last sublists of the original list. Check that the desired output is `{{1,2},{3,4},{4,5}}` where the `{3,4}` is contained  in the first list.  Comparing that to `{1, 2, 3} - 1` which just subtracts a `1` from each element is *VERY DIFFERENT*. At least in my eyes. So, I cannot see your point. Could you elaborate? Unless I misread your comment and you meant that `{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} - {1, 1}` does not work in general.

Comment: Dear OP, please clarify your intention in light of @bmf 's comment above.

Comment: @Syed for better or for worse a solution is provided for either situation :-)

Comment: I think this question is unclear because the code clearly suggests one operating while the output clearly suggests a different one. And the output could easily e a typo.

Comment: @MichaelE2 *could easily e a typo* ... pun intended?

Comment: @bmf. See what I mean? ;) ;)

Comment: Life works in style many times :-) I agree that some further elaboration is needed in the OP. It seems as a strange typo to be honest. A mistake in subtraction, sure. To forget to delete a sublist, or something like that. I

Comment: You can use the new [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html) operator: `{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} - Threaded[{1, 1}]` gives `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SubsetMap[#-1&,  {{2,3},{3,4},{5,6}}, {1,-1}]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

But perhaps you simply want the following?

```
 {{2,3},{3,4},{5,6}} - 1

 (* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

---

### **1. Subtracting from the first and last sublists only**

---

The lists given in the OP are

```
list1 = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
list2 = {1, 1};
```

and the desired output is:

```
opoutput = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}
```

One way of achieving this is the following:

```
suggestion = MapAt[# - 1 &, list1, {1 ;; ;; 2}];
```

**Quick check**

```
opoutput - suggestion
```

gives

> `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

---

### **2. Subtracting from all sublists**

---

**In case of a typo**

If there's a typo in the desired output of the OP and the `{1,1}` is to be subtracted from each sublist, then the following works nicely.

```
Map[Subtract[#, list2] &]@list1
```

and gives

> `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}`

as expected.

---